# Get index of li in multiple parents

Tags: jquery

I have a loop through all the elements in each li. What I'm trying to do is find the index of each el relative to the group-fields div. 
I have an array of all the el's inside the each li tag.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var el = arr[i];
      var li = el.closest('li');
      console.log( "li index =", li.index() );
}
```

The above is giving me the index relative to each parent which is the index of each li inside col-1 and then index of each li inside of col-2. I want to know the index of each element in relation to the top most element group-fields.

**loose HTML Example:**

```
<div class="group-fields">
  <div class="col-1">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>el</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <ul>
      <li>
         <div>el</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `arr`? Where do you define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var index = $(li).closest('.group-fields').find('li').index( li );
```

Below I am just using the `click` event for demonstration purposes only:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  //this is how to:::
  var index = $(this).closest('.group-fields').find('li').index( this );
  console.log( 'You clicked li with index = ' + index );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-fields">
  <div class="col-1">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>el</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <ul>
      <li>
         <div>el</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input>el</input>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the same it's not finding the index in relation to group-fields.

Comment: Yea I tried that but it's still not returning the correct index values.

Comment: What are the correct/expected values? You might want to create a demo.

Comment: result should be 0 - 5 in the above example. 0 being the first li inside col-1 and 3 being the first element inside of col-2 and so on.....

Comment: That's EXACTLY what this demo does.

Comment: Sorry you are right it is doing this. Not sure what is going on in my code as it's way to large to just copy and paste into here. I'm trying to do a jsFiddle example of the structure I have. But you have me on the right track. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 console.log( "li index =", li.index() );
```

The code above is wrong. It should be

```
console.log( "li index ="+ i );
```

Also, I do not know what function index() comes from.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's index requires that you give the parent set and then look for the index of the child in that set. So the first thing is to get a reference to all of the elements inside of the element with class `group-fields` and then iterate through the set of elements inside of the nested `li` elements of that parent. By using an array, you can store these elements and their index references.

```js
var inputs = [];
var parent = $('.group-fields *')
parent.find('li *').each(function(){
 console.log(this);
 console.log(parent.index(this));
 inputs.push({ el: this, index: parent.index(this) });
});
console.log(inputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-fields">
  <div class="col-1">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input value="el" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <input value="el" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>el</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <ul>
      <li>
         <div>el</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input value="el" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <input value="el" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```